# Knockout bundle not generated correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, bundle

I have the following bundle defined:

```
var knockoutBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js");
```

however when the application is published with `debug="false"` it generates the following HTML

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery.js?v=Cr8InFU-vbrPmGYYWNIXAturiBR7q9wkkgxep6VV4EU1"></script>
<script src="/bundles/bootstrap.js?v=GTjK0zIjX1_Mx7GIKofGDUgYcnSrCJvTYHNkjkMKWC01"></script>
<script src="/bundles/knockout.js?v="></script>
```

and the link for knockout is empty (also note that there is no v= value)

If i change debug to `true` it generates this and works fine:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `.debug` suffix in your bundle definition:

```
var knockoutBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js");
```

Now when running in Debug mode this will generate:

```
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js"></script>
```

and when running in Release mode:

```
<script src="/bundles/knockout.js?v=VqZ0J9f3e7QvvRrMNGAzEkpXKvaJMNRA8LqjNIoUGqs1"></script>
```

Obviously this assumes that you have both `knockout-2.3.0.debug.js` and `knockout-2.2.0.js` in your Scripts folder. The bundling engine will use the right file based on the whether your application is running in Debug or Release mode.

Comment: that worked. thanks. i thought i can get the debug version and just apply `new JsMinify()` in Release mode. I guess it ignores .debug.js all together.